# class for Android Views

Tags: android

```
public class myView(){

AutoCompleteTextView textView;

     public myView(COUNTRIES){

             AutoCompleteTextView textView = new AutoCompleteTextView(this);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, COUNTRIES);
        textView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    public AutoCompleteTextView getAutoView(){
         return textView;
    }
}
```

I put AutoCompleteTextView in a seperate class and I tried to use it making a object of this class. But this didn't work, Can u give me an idea how can I make separate class for some Views in android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [Modifying an Existing View Type](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html#modifying) for a simple example.